# Conjuctive Normal Form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In Boolean logic, a formula is in conjunctive normal form or clausal normal form if it is a conjunction of clauses, where a clause is a disjunction of literals; otherwise put, it is an AND of ORs.

I See that this formula

[image]

in CNF form is equivalent to

[image]

I try to convert it, but I'm failed. I think maybe it's not equivalent. one expert please help me step by step.

Comment: Please, type the formulae, instead of inserting images; it is easier for potential answerer to copy them, avoiding the extra-effort of retyping ... :)

Comment: thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, would you please submit as an answer? thanks a lot. okey I try to type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to "unwid" $(¬A→B)↔¬C$ as :

> $[(¬A→B)→¬C)]∧[¬C→(¬A→B)]$

and then use the equivalence between :

> $(¬A→B)$ and $(A∨B)$

and :

> $(A→B)$ and $(¬A∨B)$.

Thus :

*(i)* $(¬A→B)↔¬C$

*(ii)* $[(¬A→B)→¬C)]∧[¬C→(¬A→B)]$

*(iii)* $[(A \lor B) \rightarrow \lnot C] \land [\lnot C \rightarrow (A \lor B)]$

*(iv)* $[\lnot (A \lor B) \lor \lnot C] \land [C \lor (A \lor B)]$

*(v)* $[(\lnot A \land \lnot B) \lor \lnot C] \land (A \lor B \lor C)$ --- by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

> > *(vi)* $[(\lnot A \lor \lnot C) \land (\lnot B \lor \lnot C)] \land (A \lor B \lor C)$ --- by [Distributive laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)